# Adding users to another blog (Wordpress Multisite)

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

Good Morning...

I want to make a snippet that when creating a user in a blog add it automatically to another blog (this number 1 always) with the same roll that was created.

For this I am using this:

```
$ Blog_id = 1;
$ User_id = get_current_user_id ();
$ Role = 'publisher';
Add_action ('user_register', add_user_to_blog ($ blog_id, $ user_id, $ role));
```

.....And it does not work,

but if I do this....

```
$ Blog_id = 1;
$ User_id = 127; // 127 is a specific number of a user that already exists
$ Role = 'publisher';
Add_action ('user_register', add_user_to_blog ($ blog_id, $ user_id, $ role));
```

Then yes that works.

Can someone help me understand why the first (generic) solution does not work with:

```
$ User_id = get_current_user_id (); ?
```

Comment: Why do you put a space between $ and the var name? Also, does `Add_action` works with a capital letter? Finally, where exactly are you using this code? It's better if you show your real usage instead of pseudo-code...

Comment: You're right ... there should not be a separation between $ and variable. Something has happened while doing copy + paste ...

Answer (score 1):

[get_current_user_id](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/) function returns the current logged in user. It's not new user ID.

> Get the current user’s ID

You should use something like this:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {
    $blog_id = 1;
    add_user_to_blog($blog_id, $user_id, "publisher");

}
```

I didn't test it but it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks ... but I have tried it and it does not work. I think it is a good idea to pass the function $ user_id but the problem is that in the moment of creating a new user does not know what $ user_id is (I think).
You're right, get_current_user_id returns the value of the user logged id but not the new ...
Can you think of anything else?
Thank you very vey much

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
add_action( 'wpmu_activate_user', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );
function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {
    $blog_id = 13;
    add_user_to_blog($blog_id, $user_id, "subscriber");
}
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30791663)